# Can't read from my src/main/resources directory

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn more about how to read files in Java.

Currently I have some code that will read a file from the same directory:

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource(fileName).getPath());

    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            result.append(line).append("\n");
        }

        scanner.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My issue is when I try to move my file into the resources directory.

```
File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).getFile());
```

I can read the file from the resources directory with an InputStream, but I'm trying to avoid doing that way. The file variable is what I would expect to work, but it doesn't.

Does anyone have advice on where I should go from here?

Comment: *Why* are you trying to avoid doing it the correct way?

Comment: does you class live in a package? have you placed your file to read in the same (package-) directory structure under `/src/main/resources`

Comment: I'm trying to avoid saving the file to memory.

Comment: My class is in the src/main/java directory. It is in the resources directory, but I can't find it.

Comment: @AdamYoung: *"I'm trying to avoid saving the file to memory"* that's nonsense, nothing is "save" in memory and the meaning of "saving" something is to write it **from** memory to some more durable place.

Comment: Here is the structure of my project: http://i67.tinypic.com/2i6ndix.png

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Is there a negative side to reading a file this way?

Comment: *"Is there a negative side to reading a file this way?"* The negative side is that you obviously not know what you're talking about. (sorry, if this sounds like an insult, this is not intended...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving this issue:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("main/resources/" + fileName).getFile());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/"+fileName).getFile());
```

if the file is at the root of `src/main/resources` folder and you use Maven.

Comment: It stills throws a java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Your problem is there. src/main/resources is a default classpath for resources when your project use maven (or gradle) as you can read in my answer.

Comment: You should read :https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html

Answer (score -1):

Could you try the following?
       
`ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());`

Comment: That still returned the same NullPointerException